# LinqPad Can I connect/and query a runtime object

Tags: c#, connection, runtime, linqpad

I have a List with a lot of nested objects. And lines down a Linq Query very, very big.
I execute and put a breakpoint here and ask... Can I connect LinqPad to Visual Studio debugger or take the dll, exe, anything, for get this list, and after in LinqPad make simplified query.

In LinqPad connections wizard exist these options: Linq to SQL, Entity Framework or (Linq to SQL "default") WCF Data Services, Microsoft DataMarketService. And none of them seems make this work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that exact thing; however, there might be another way to reach your goal.  What is your end goal?  What do you want to do if you could hypothetically connect to this list with linqpad?

Comment: For the Visual Studio debugger part there is an excellent description [here](http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/21154-attaching-a-debugger-till-linqpad/) which may be from the same "sgmoore" as her at SO. Is it, @sgmoore? Maybe bring it in as an answer.

Comment: @GertArnold, I think that's the other way around. The post talks about attaching VS debugger to LINQPad query. What I think OP wants is “attaching” LINQPad to code running in VS debugger.

Comment: @ROMANARMY My goal is use LinqPad to make query for an runtime object, use the runtime object "as a" Entity for example(but my runtime Object isn't a Entity, for this example my runtime object is a List, but this List is instantiated(get data) from a hide place, dll... if this list was instantiated in the current method or in a visible place, don't have sense ask "Can I connect/and query a runtime object".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a method that returns the big list, you can call that from LINQPad. To do that, press F4 in LINQPad, add a reference to your assembly (.dll or .exe) and optionally add the namespace of your class to namespace imports.

This won't connect you to VS debugger, but directly to the class you are creating.

Comment: Well the I did that minutes before ask, and appears: Use of unassigned local variable 'myObject'; myObject receive data from another dll that was connected to WCF.

Comment: My method doesn't return a big list, inside my method a short list of 4 items it's returned by a big linq query that contains nested select, sum, avg